# Variable not modifying divCount

Tags: javascript

I have been learning javascript and I have been hung up on this for a while. I am trying to add 1 each time the button is pressed, and it is not doing so, it is simply staying at 0.

```
 <input id="numberBox" size="10" type="text">
<br><br>
<input value="Double!" 
onclick="var n = document.getElementById('numberBox').value;
n = n * 2;
document.getElementById('numberBox').value = n";
input type="button">
<br>
<br>
<input value="Reset Number of Clicks" onclick="document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = 0;" type="button">
</p>
<hr>
    <script>
        var count = document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML;
        count ++;
        document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = count;
    </script>
    <div id='divCount'>0</div>
```

I am still learning so forgive me if it is a silly mistake. Thanks.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id='divCount'>0</div>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="oneUp();" />

<script>
function oneUp()
 {
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML, 10);
    count ++;
    document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = count;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The info really helped out and I learned a bit more about functions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to ensure that `count` is an integer actually before attemoting to increment it:

```
<script>
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML, 10);
    count ++;
    document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = count;
</script>
```

The `innerHTML` property that you are calling returns a string. And it makes little sense to perform the `++` operation on a string. You'd rather do that on a number. The second argument indicates the base when parsing the string, which in this case is decimal (10).

Also make sure thta you have placed this script after the div you are manipulating:

```
<div id="divCount">0</div>

<script>
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML, 10);
    count ++;
    document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = count;
</script>
```

or by the time you are calling `document.getElementById('divCount')` you might get null because the DOM is not yet fully loaded.

Comment: I added the parseInt function so the digit would not be a string anymore, yet the value still stays at 0. I will update my original post for more code. The idea is that the user enters a number and it is doubled and also shows the number of clicks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2946457 because your div is after the script (its undefined in script) move the script after your div tag

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, good point, I have updated my answer to take it into account.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Thank you for the input. When I do this, the script automatically adds one to the 0 and doesn't modify it when the user presses the button. I am unsure of how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @user2946457 have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You must have the element yet created when you execute your script and you must parse the string to increment it :

```
<div id='divCount'>0</div>
<script>
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML, 10);
    count ++;
    document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = count;
</script>
```

If you don't want to put the script after the elements (or if your JS code is in a separate file imported in the header), you may put the content in a function executed on load :

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('load', function(){
        var count = parseInt(document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML, 10);
        count ++;
        document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = count;
    });
</script>
<div id='divCount'>0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this parseInt() function:

```
<script>
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML);
    count++;
    document.getElementById('divCount').innerHTML = count;
</script>
<div id='divCount'>0</div>
```